# getting and setting global vars in c#?

Tags: c#, global-variables

first of all i would like to say i know its probably an easy question, but what i found on google and this forum couldnt help me understand the getters and setters in c#;

I'm trying to create global vars for my webapplication.

I'm coming from Java, and i don't get how the setter and getter exactly work.

I made a class globalvars, and want to set a var in there, this is the simplified version of what im trying

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Threading;
using MvcApplication2.Controllers;

namespace MvcApplication2
{
public static class Globals {
public static int Lang { get; set; }
}
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    Globals.Lang = 5;
    HomeController hc = new HomeController("nl");
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {

        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
//more code

instead of setLang I have tried 

MvcApplication2.MvcApplication.Global.setLang(5);
Global.setLang(5);
MvcApplication2.Global.setLang(5);

but they all say the method does not exist in my namespace.
```

I figure my mistake will be in initializing the setter/variable, but what is the proper     way to do this?

EDIT : mistake in my exammple fixed

EDIT:  Globals.Lang = 5; can only be used inside a method??????

Edit: my actual code

Comment: Why have you written `namespace MvcApplication2;` isn't it should be `namespace MvcApplication2 { class abc { //... } }`

Comment: By "can only be used in a method", do you mean what you actually want is a constant? Something you set once and always has that value?

Comment: no its the language setting, when the user presses a button i want it to change

Comment: In that case, given that the value is specific to a user's sessions you should instead be using Session/cookies to store this value

Comment: wow, i would expect this to be the the easy part of this project, 1 day spent internationalizing, already two days working on a button to set the language lol, god i miss java :P

Comment: haha, you're just unfamiliar with the paradigm. Stick the value in the session, `Session["language"] = 5;` and be done with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set a property as you would set a public field so in your case it would be

```
Globals.Lang = //some int value;
```

That set you should really, I mean really re-consider your use of global (hard coded) values like this. They quite often become a nightmare when it comes to testing and versioning

you have written your lasting problem as an edit. You can't access anything outside of method scope. You can only initialize fields of the current class so you'd need to move your assignment into a method (include constructors)

In your example you could do this

```
static MvcApplication(){
   Globals.Lang = 5;
}
```

That will create a static constructor for your MvcApplication class and assign to the `Globals.Lang` property.

I still would advice you not to do this but to at least load the values from some storage

you also comment that you wish to remember the selected language. Using globals it will change for **all** users at the same time. There's only one value for the AppDomain (Ie AppPool)

Comment: @BartHofma the above code does not try to use it as a type (you can't assign to a type) what does your code look like?

Comment: Why the dv? The answer explains what OP is facing and how to remedy that

Comment: @BartHofma I've extended my example to try and show you the fix to your problem

Comment: okay thanks, best answer , i got it to work (was missing constructor at class start) but u convinced me not to use global variables :P
i didnt know it would change language for all users i thought the global scope would mean that all pages could acces it, but still could have different values for different users

Answer (score 3):

With the answer below for completeness, I would advise that you try to stay away from "globals" in the traditional sense and also stay away from `static` members in ASP.NET applications. `static` members are scoped to an AppDomain, which IIS will inadvertantly recycle when it manages worker processes. This means any value you set in there is lost, and it will revert to the default value on next access.

---

What you have written (`public static int Lang { get; set; }`) is an auto-implementing property, which is actually a particular style of a normal property. It avoids you having to define fields as well as the wrapping property. The old manual way is this:

```
private static int _lang;

public static int Lang
{
    get { return _lang; }
    set { _lang = value; }
}
```

Property access syntactically behaves just like fields in C#, so:

```
Globals.Lang = 2;
```

Is how you set and:

```
int value = Globals.Lang;
```

Is how you get.

---

Your attempts include trying to fully qualify the `Globals` class (which is required in-line or via `using` statements).

Answer (score 0):

instead of setLang("EN");, try this

```
Globals.Lang = Some_INT_Value; // or "EN" if the property is of string type
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your `Lang` property is an `int` yet you're trying to set to string, so first change that.

Then you would set the variable as such:

```
Globals.Lang = 5; //assuming it was meant to be an int not string
```

Comment: @V4Vendetta look at the history, it was being set to "EN" in the original question.

Comment: @vipw No idea if `setLang` actually sets the value for `int Lang`

Comment: @V4Vendetta taking from the Java background and the wording in the question I think it's safe to assume than when OP talks about a setter he's expecting something that follows the Java naming convention for setters (seeing that he has a method fitting that convention in his code)

Comment: @RuneFS Ok ! maybe nonetheless i am still blown off that its setting something which is `public` in normal cases i have seen them as private only.

Comment: yea that was my bad, i edited it but that s not my problem(the int/string thing)

Comment: @Rune Fs, this was my assumption also

Comment: true, i am trying java syntax things :P

Comment: but to expand on this, why can i do Global.Lang=5 only in a method and not at class start?? (is property but used like type)

Comment: How would the code execute if it is not in a method somewhere? You can only do in-place assignments on fields.

Comment: it would be executed at class creation right? uggggm what m i saying, i need a constructor i think....

Comment: yes, providing it is an instance field. For a static class i guess it would be when the static constructor is implictly executed (which is when a member of the class is first utilised). If `const` then it is a compile time constant and is never set at run time